How do I get the methods (with parameters) of a Python class while keeping the original order of the methods?
The dir() function prints the methods in alphabetical order. Is there a way to get the methods of a class (with their parameters) but keeping the original order of the methods?
Here's my code
return [
    (m, getattr(PythonClass, m).__code__.co_varnames)
    for m in dir(PythonClass)
]


PythonClass.__dict__ contains the methods in the original order.

But it doesn't have inherited methods.

@Barmar thanks! But I want the names of the method's arguments as well. Maybe I can just do it the way I'm doing and separately call PythonClass.dict to get the order...

Why on EARTH do you care a whit about the order of the methods?  What possible difference could that make to anyone?  Good engineering just pretends that methods don't HAVE an order.

@TimRoberts I'm using the method names to dynamically print a list of inputs on the UI, so that I don't have to make a UI change everytime I create or update or delete a method... and the order matters in my use case...

This is dangerous practice.  You should think again  You're relying on implementation details that might change.  Remember that in Python 2, dictionaries didn't HAVE an order.  There would have been no way to determine the original ordering, and it's safer to assume that.  Will future maintainers of your code have to be warned that any utility methods they add to the class will be exposed to and callable by the end user?  What about using a decorator that adds the name to a global list?

If the order matters, put that order in a list or something rather than relying on where you define the function in the code...

In case someone is interested in answering (regardless of whether this is good practice or not), are you restricting it to just using dir() (as your question states) or are you open to any other ways of getting that list?

@GinoMempin I'm open to any ways of getting that list , as long as I get the argument names too!

As @Barmar mentioned in the comments, you can use the __dict__ attribute of a class to access its attributes. Since Python 3.7 dict keys are guaranteed to retain their insertion order, so by iterating over PythonClass.__dict__ you can obtain attributes of PythonClass in the order of definition. It is also more idiomatic to use the vars function instead of the __dict__ attribute to access the attributes dict. To filter class attributes for methods, you can use inspect.isfunction to test if an attribute is a function:
from inspect import isfunction

class PythonClass:
    var = 1
    def method_b(self, b): ...
    def method_a(self, a): ...

print([
    (name, obj.__code__.co_varnames)
    for name, obj in vars(PythonClass).items() if isfunction(obj)
])

This outputs:
[('method_b', ('self', 'b')), ('method_a', ('self', 'a'))]

Demo: https://ideone.com/rNMcYO

Explicit is better than implicit. If you want to build a list of methods, use a decorator to explicitly add them to the list. The def statements run one at a time, so the list will be built in the expected order. (Note that the list doesn't need to be a class variable, it can live wherever it makes sense in your real code.)
def add_name_and_args_to(lst: list[tuple[str, tuple[str, ...]]]):
    def decorator(func):
        lst.append((func.__name__, func.__code__.co_varnames))
        return func
    return decorator

class MyClass:
    some_list: list[tuple[str, tuple[str, ...]]] = []

    @add_name_and_args_to(some_list)
    def foo(self, arg)
        ...

    @add_name_and_args_to(some_list)
    def bar(self, arg1, arg2):
        ...

    def baz(self, arg): # no decorator, so this won't be listed
        ...

# prints [('foo', ('self', 'arg')), ('bar', ('self', 'arg1', 'arg2'))]
print(MyClass.some_list)

